# Dell Laptop overheated while shutown

Tags: laptop, battery, shutdown, overheating

Recently, I did shutdown my laptop and, when shutdown, it overheated and drained the whole battery out in about an hour or two.

I just got lucky that I touched it and realized that it was really hot. I then tried to start it up again, had to plug it back in for it to have battery, even though it was full an hour ago. Then upon start-up the fan started and cooled down the machine. No I've stopped it again and it is not overheating again. During the overheating while shutdown, the laptop was unplugged.

I'm worried by the overheating problem as it look pretty dangerous to me. The laptop was really hot and could have burned itself (or maybe other things). 
I have two questions:

- I have a 4 year warranty on the machine, should I return it, even though the problem might not be easily reproducible?
- What could have caused the overheating while shutdown?

Comment: "What could have caused the overheating while shutdown?" - Inadequate airflow which could be caused by dust. Your laptop should not be overheating, if it is overheating, then it is a hardware problem.

Comment: But it wasn't hot when I stopped it. I only let it run for 1min to test a screen prior to the overheating while shutdown.

Comment: You say it was shutdown but how sure are you? Could you have clicked shutdown, closed the lid before it could warn you that an application was preventing shutdown, and ended up putting it in a bag while it was effectively still on?

Comment: I had no process running because I've only plugged and unplugged a screen (and fedora would have killed it anyway on shutdown). For the lid, I'm running a test now where I closed the lid while it is still on. It has not lost any battery yet and is not overheating.

Comment: @Malcolm - "I touched it and realized that it was really hot." - Your laptop shouldn't be "really hot" if it's working as designed.